# Customer Login not working after data migration From Magento 1.4.1 to Magento 2.3.3

Tags: data-migration, data-migration-tool, customer-login, customer-data

I have migrated data from Magento 1.4.1  to Magento 2.3.3 using Magento Data Migration tool. Data has migrated successfully but Magento 1 customer login not working in Magento 2.3.3. I know there is a password_hash issue. I already tried the command **php -f bin/magento customer:hash:upgrade**. and I also truncate the table "**customer_entity_var**" still  no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest going to a file name encryptor.php in the vendor folder (Path is below) vendor\magento\framework\Encryption\Encryptor.php and change isValidHash() function like below.

```
    public function isValidHash($password, $hash)
       { 
          try { 

            $this->explodePasswordHash($hash);

           foreach ($this->getPasswordVersion() as $hashVersion) {

            if ($hashVersion == '0') {

                $recreated = current(explode(':', $hash));

            }else if ($hashVersion === self::HASH_VERSION_ARGON2ID13) {
                $recreated = $this->getArgonHash($password, $this->getPasswordSalt());
            } else {

                $recreated = $this->generateSimpleHash($this->getPasswordSalt() . $password, $hashVersion);
            }

            $hash = $this->getPasswordHash();
            error_log('password changing technique ======');
            error_log(print_r($recreated,true));
            error_log(print_r($hash,true));
        }
    } catch (\RuntimeException $exception) {
        //Hash is not a password hash.
        $recreated = $this->hash($password);
    }

    return Security::compareStrings(
        $recreated,
        $hash
    ); 
}
```

And if you don't want to change the core code, you can also create a custom module.

Hope that help!